# what can the dot command repeat, exactly?

Tags: vim

Vimmers know that `.` can repeat simple changes. I tried to build a list of what can be repeated or not, but is there a list?

I tried to list what I know to be repeatable: they are all normal-mode commands:

- Text insertion : `a`, `A`, `i`, `I`, `o`, `O`
- Text changes involving registers: `c`, `C`, `d`, `D`, `p`, `gp`, `P`, `gP`, `s`, `S`,`x`, `X`
- Other text changes: `J`, `gJ`, `r`, `gr`, `R`, `gR`, `gU`, `gu`, `gw`, `gq`, `g?`, `~`, `g~`, `<`, `>`, `=`
- Equivalent of these operations in visual mode.
- Control-operations: `C-A`, `C-X`
- `gi` will repeat the insertion *but* at current cursor position, not at last insert position. So it *sort of* works.

But it does not include:

- All move and display commands (too numerous to be listed here)
- All fold commands (z-commands, also numerous)
- Mark (`m`)
- Substitution repeat (`&`, `g&`)
- Colon or Filter command (`!`, `:`, `Q`)
- Macro recordings or playing (`q` or `@`, will repeat last repeatable action done while recording or playing ).
- Diff put and get (`dp`, `do`)
- Undo (`u`, `U`, `C-R`)
- Yanks (`y`)

I know that tpope's [repeat](https://github.com/tpope/vim-repeat) plugin can have custom plugins subscribe to the repetition mechanism. But by default, is the above list good?

Comment: I would venture to say it probably repeats anything that `undo` would undo.  I can't think of anything off the top of my head that conflicts with that statement (but I haven't used vim in a while now so things are becoming fuzzy). Maybe it's easier to find a list of things `undo` will undo than it is to find a list of things `.` will repeat.

Comment: @RandyMorris "undo" could undo cmd line (e.g. :s/foo/bar/) changes, but "." cannot repeat them.

Comment: AFAK, "c, C, ..." can be repeated using "."

Comment: Ctrl-A ctrl-X to do the number changes can be "dot"-repeated as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe a *change* is any command that modifies the current buffer. The `.` command excludes Ex commands (because that's a different mode that was bolted onto vi in the far history, I guess), and can optionally include yanks.

So for your list, `:help change.txt`, filtered for Ex commands, is probably the best source.

Note that when a change command cannot be applied (i.e. it beeps), it is also not registered for repeat; the command execution must be successful.

Comment: I have the _feeling_ that your answer is accurate, intuitively, however it is not because `.` does not repeat `&` nor `g&`.

Comment: `&` and `g&` themselves repeat a command (last `:s`), so I guess that's the reason to exclude them.

Answer (score 2):

some combination with v/V can be "dot" repeated too.

e.g.

Vgq, v/VU or v/Vu

Answer (score 1):

Tim Pope's `repeat.vim` can make `repeat` many more things (including stuff like `surround.vim` and other must haves).

To repeat a motion, look at <kbd>,</kbd> / <kbd>;</kbd> (forward/reverse direction).

To repeat an Ex command, <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> is a good key combination

Comment: I know about repeat.vim (it is mentioned in the question). Yes, `;,` can repeat `fFtT` motions. Maybe also mention `nN`.

Comment: @Benoit Oh. I completely overlooked the mention. I think I used `/repeat` to scan for mentions on the whole page... Sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

#### Insert mode expression register is NOT re-evaluated

Example: If you want to sort following inline lists of numbers,

```
 first 3,2,17,198,232,1,999 and some other text
 second 1,2,3,71,98,4,5 and some more text
```

consider these two ways using the expression register:

1. `ciW` and then `<C-r>=join(sort([<C-r>"]), ',')<CR>`
2. `ciW` and then `<C-r>=join(sort(split(expand(@"), ',')), ',')<CR>`

If you try to repeat either of them for the second line with `.`, vim simply enters again the same list from the first line.
This might be expected by others but I was hoping that for the second way the expression register would be re-evaluated.