# A more powerful version of dot (repeat)

Tags: vim

I know about recording with `q` into registers, but I was wondering if it's possible to set something up to quickly recall the last recording, in much the same way that `.` recalls the last short editing command (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566235/what-can-the-dot-command-repeat-exactly?rq=1) for a discussion on `.`).

I know about `@@` but it only seems to work after doing `@z` where `z` is the register used. 
e.g. to make the recording you must type `qz`, go on to do your thing, `q`, and then in order to run the recording you must `@z` before you can start `@@`-ing to repeat that.

My hack solution now is a bind `nnoremap , @q` which lets me do recordings with `qq` and ending them with `q`. Is there something better (e.g. something that records into a particular register with a single keystroke, **or** something that specifically repeats the last-recorded macro)? admittedly that isn't a huge improvement, as it's pretty optimal already.

For me a single register that is easy to use is generally more useful than a large number of registers that require a bit more work to get at. Though this could just be that I'm bad at remembering things and don't see myself effectively making use of more than one.

Comment: @@ works for any macro in my vim. So ... painful as it may be, what vim and what platform are you on?

Comment: @RamRajamony I think the question is about executing the last recorded macro as opposed to the last invoked macro.

Comment: If you mostly use just one register for macros I actually think your solution is pretty good. I map Q to @j myself, and qj is easy to press!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try some plugins that do something similar to what you asked:

[RepeatLast.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4381) and 
[record-repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2873)

Another option could be use some function and associate it with [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136).

Comment: repeat.vim might be promising. It's clearly not worth it to pursue this though. Those other options feel inferior to my existing no-plugin-needed binding.

Answer (score 2):

Since you like to use the same register for all your macros and just record over it as needed, you can set and execute that register in your _vimrc file so that `@@` is "primed".

In your _vimrc file, add:

```
let @z = ''
execute 'normal @z'
```

Now, as soon as you record a macro in register `z`, you can immediately execute it with `@@`.

Comment: Interesting though this feels like a set-up for strange behavior in the future. What'd be nice is if there is just something that tracks the last macro.